# I want to know how to lock transfer of pNFT token account

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

I have made a pNFT and then transferred it to other account.
Now what I want to do is that, I want to lock transfer of token account which currently has the NFT.
I have read this https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/issues/470 article but I don't know how can I be the delegate of the token account.
Please help me.
I would appreciate for any kind of help or clue.

Answer (score 1):

While minting a NFT the mint authority and freeze authority both are transfered to the Master Edition account. As a result you have to go through the metaplex functions to achieve this. There is no function for minting as it is a NFT but use the `createFreezeDelegatedAccountInstruction` to freeze the token mint account.

To freeze a token account you first need to be the delegate of the token account. The creator of the token account needs to call the `anchor_spl::token::approve` function. Below is the rust docs for the same:

https://docs.rs/anchor-spl/latest/anchor_spl/token/fn.approve.html#

If you are using javascript for this you need to call the `approve` function in `anchor-spl` or `solana-spl` whichever package you are using:

```
// Approve the above associated token address to spend the SFT
    await approve({
        connection: connection,
        payer: wallet, 
        account: masterEditionAddress,
        delegate: delegateAddress, 
        owner: wallet.publicKey, 
        amount: token(1) // As it is a NFT it will be one
    });
```

Also you can use `createApproveInstruction` to create instruction and then add to transaction for the same result.

Then you can call the freeze account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tushar sahoo.  Have you tested it?
What you did is SFT and What I want to do is pNFT

Comment: I couldn't approve because the token is pNFT